# Installation ORACLE 11g in an external hardrive

Tags: oracle

I am working on a project in which i have to deal with oracle 11g.
My project manager wants me to install Oracle 11g in an external hard drive. I already installed it in the hard drive, though when you browse and open sql developer it asks me to input a source to the JDK. When I input a source it does not work and then the same pop up comes back.

Please help me in this? 
Thank You

---

Just to let you know I am using Windows for this. When I plugin the hard drive that has oracle installed in it does not work. When I open the files which has a file called sql developer and i open that file a pop up opens everytime and it asks me to input a path name for the JDK. After inputting the source the same pop up comes again. I just wanted to knwo whether it is possible to install the software in the hard  drive, so that i can work on an alternative

Regards

Comment: There is also a DBA stack (which may be more appropriate than serverfault?)

Comment: Please provide more information. Can you `tnsping` the database? What error does it give you? Windows or Linux? Is pmon running? Is the listener running? Anything in the error logs? Is networking set up correctly? Are you trying to run the database on the same machine as the client?

Answer (score 2):

Broadly, you can't run oracle in a 'portable' manner. You install it on a server and leave it there. It's not even happy with a dynamic IP address.

Your best bet is install Oracle in a Virtual Machine such as VMWare or VirualBox (which is an Oracle product). Bear in mind that Oracle is a database and spends a lot of time reading and writing datafiles. Virtual machines also do a lot of disk IO.

A basic external hard-drive (USB 2.0) is going to very slow for this sort of work.

There's a pre-build VM running Oracle's free version (XE) at:
http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/virtualbox